# Search text file for string with today's date

Tags: python

I'm wanting to search a text file for a certain string with today's date, this is what i have so far

```
with open('//HASSIO/config/appdaemon/appdaemon.log', 'r') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        if 'INFO alarm Trigger: alarm Alert_on_0: @ ' in line:
            print line
```

as you can see below it pull all the lines with the string yet i'm only wanting the line created with today's date

what i would like to search is = "Trigger: alarm Alert_on_0: @ current date"

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python c:\scripts\test.py
2019-08-01 10:54:12.301668 INFO alarm Trigger:alarm Alert_on_0: @ 2019-08-01 21:18:56

2019-08-01 15:46:48.797446 INFO alarm Trigger:alarm Alert_on_0: @ 2019-08-01 21:07:23

2019-08-01 16:27:49.101543 INFO alarm Trigger:alarm Alert_on_0: @ 2019-08-01 21:10:46

2019-08-01 19:31:04.752357 INFO alarm Trigger:alarm Alert_on_0: @ 2019-08-01 21:24:19

2019-08-02 03:00:00.163624 INFO alarm Trigger:alarm Alert_on_0: @ 2019-08-02 21:23:59

2019-08-02 13:07:51.993228 INFO alarm Trigger:alarm Alert_on_0: @ 2019-08-02 21:24:41
```

**2019-08-03 19:22:49.987171 INFO alarm Trigger: alarm Alert_on_0: @ 2019-08-03 21:18:34**

if really possible i don't want the full line just: **alarm Alert_on_0: @ 2019-08-03 21:18:34**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get todays date and search for it

```py
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
# YYYY-mm-dd
d1 = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print(d1)
with open('//HASSIO/config/appdaemon/appdaemon.log', 'r') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        if 'INFO alarm Trigger: alarm Alert_on_0: @ '+d1 in line:
            print(line.split('Trigger:')[1])
```

Comment: Updated with @samuelbob's solution

Answer (score 2):

To add to Jammy Dodger's reply and answer your second question (only print text after `Trigger:`):

```
print(line.split('Trigger:')[1])
```